# ruby on rails carrierwave-video ffmpeg AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, amazon-web-services, ffmpeg

I am trying to create an academic site where users can upload lecture videos and other users can view them - similar to a site like Udemy.

I am using Carrierwave, Carrierwave-video (for encoding videos), AWS to make this happen. AWS configuration has been done, and it's working.

However, I am getting this error. (By the way, I am testing this video feature in a Yelpdemo site, so I am trying to have users upload videos to restaurants for now.)

rails points the error to @restaurant = Restaurant.new(restaurant_params)

Errno::ENOENT in RestaurantsController#create

No such file or directory - ffmpeg

# POST /restaurants.json
  def create
    @restaurant = Restaurant.new(restaurant_params)

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @restaurant.save
```

This is my video_uploader.rb

```
# encoding: utf-8

class VideoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::Video
  include CarrierWave::Video::Thumbnailer

  process encode_video: [:mp4]

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

   version :thumb do
      process thumbnail: [{format: 'png', quality: 10, size: 192, strip: true, logger: Rails.logger}]
      def full_filename for_file
        png_name for_file, version_name
      end
  end

    def png_name for_file, version_name
      %Q{#{version_name}_#{for_file.chomp(File.extname(for_file))}.png}
    end
end
```

I have manually (added a file to the model) created video.rb in the model - not sure if this is the right way to do it..

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :user_id, :video,, :type, :filename, :path, :filesize, :width, :height, :duration, :bit_rate

  belongs_to :restaurant
  belongs_to :user

  mount_uploader :video, VideoUploader
end
```

in app/views/restaurants/show.html.erb  for showing the video. Right now, without the encoding done, I can see like an image of the video. When I right lick and copy the code - it gives me the AWS URL which means AWS configuration is in place

```
        <p>
            <strong>Video:</strong>
            <%= video_tag @restaurant.video_url %>
        </p>
```

I am trying to show videos like this.

I have downloaded FFMPEG (both ffmpeg-2.6 and SnowLeopard_Lion_Mountain_Yosemite_17) - not sure which one's the right one.. And I have read somewhere that you need to place FFMPEG in your usr/local/bin   -> So do you have to physically place ffmpeg exec file in your respective folder?

Need your expert help please.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve your problem is remove your AMI AWS instance and create new base on Ubuntu. In this case you can without any problems install FFMPEG out of the box use:

```
apt-get install ffmpeg
```

otherwise you have 2 ways:

1. [Build](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos) FFMPEG from sources. + you will have additional troubles with paths and permissions.
2. Try to find RPM package or RPM repository compatible with your AMI instance and install FFMPEG from it

So, I just recommend to re-build your instance with Ubuntu.

Comment: Could you please further explain creating a new base on Ubuntu (I have never used Ubuntu before), and What does AMI stand for when you say AMI AWS? Thank you!

Comment: I have ran apt-get install ffmpeg on my console, but it's saying that apt-get command is not found.

Comment: [AMI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html) - default Amazon instance base on CentOS or RedHat (I don't known exactly). Just create new instance in EC2 base on Ubuntu instead of that default instance type.