# Argument error while encoding video in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ffmpeg, carrierwave

I am trying to upload video and convert it into mp4. For conversion I am using the gem **carrierwave-video**. My configuration as same in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28980736/ruby-on-rails-carrierwave-video-ffmpeg-aws)

I have installed ffmpeg in my system. But when I upload video the following error occurs.

```
VideoFailed to transcode with FFmpeg. Check ffmpeg install and verify video is not corrupt or cut short. Original error: ArgumentError
```

When I comment the line

```
 process encode_video: [:mp4]
```

in VideoUploader. It works fine, but conversion is not happening. Is there any issue in passing parameters. Please give your valuable answers

Comment: I was able to convert it using the command line. 
COMMAND : **ffmpeg -i /video.mp4  -target pal-dvd -ps 2000000000 -aspect 16:9 /video.mpeg**

Comment: what is your streamio-ffmpeg and ruby version

Comment: streamio-ffmpeg (version: 3.0.2)
ruby (version: 2.3.0p0)
rails (version: 4.2.1)

Comment: your version seems to have no issue can you try 
movie = FFMPEG::Movie.new("path/to/movie.mov")
movie.transcode("movie.mp4") { |progress| puts progress }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find the solution for carrierwave-video gem, so I used the [Voyeur gem](https://github.com/devthenet/voyeur) instead of carrierwave-video.I was able to convert videos using this gem. I will appreciate, if any fix for my issue is found. Thank you

Comment: The Voyeur gem is not maintained as you can see the last commit was 5 years ago.i am using paperclip and just ffmpeg to convert all my videos in mp4,webm and ogg.Let me know if you need some help....

Comment: Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory - ffmpeg):
birdseed_videochat    |   
birdseed_videochat    | app/models/concerns/encode_and_upload.rb:14:in ``'
birdseed_videochat    | app/models/concerns/encode_and_upload.rb:14:in `encode'

i am facing this error and i am also converting my video to mp4 and webm.

Answer (score 0):

Try providing extra parameters.

For eg.

`process encode_video: [:mp4, resolution: :same]`

change resolution as per you needs.

Comment: Its not the issue with the resolution. I have added a custom resolution as well